# Hadoop Pig: Passing Command Line Arguments

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way to do this? eg, pass the name of the file to be processed, etc?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This showed up in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structure), but you can indicate the input parameter on the command line and use that when you are loading, for example:

Command Line:

> pig -f script.pig -param input=somefile.txt

script.pig:

> raw = LOAD '$input' AS (...);

Note that if you are using the Amazon Web Services Elastic Map Reduce then the '$input' is what is passed to the script for any input you provide.

Comment: What if we have to pass Timestamp in format of (2015-08-06 04:54:49), in my case it is throwing error - Relative path in absolute URI: 04:36:33. that is because of colon that we are using in timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ... 
1. if there are few parameters then use -param (-p)
2. if there are lot of parameters then use -param_file (-m)

You can use either approach depending on the nature of value of your command line arguments, I use -param when i am developing and testing my scripts. Once pig script is ready for batch processing or running thru crontab, I use -param_file so that if any change required, I can easily update the params.init file.

man pig will show you all available options.

```
-m, -param_file path to the parameter file
-p, -param key value pair of the form param=val
```

Here is sample code ...

#### students.txt (input data)

```
001,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Hyderabad
002,siddarth,Battacharya,22,9848022338,Kolkata
003,Rajesh,Khanna,22,9848022339,Delhi
004,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,Pune
005,Trupthi,Mohanthy,23,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar
006,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai
007,Komal,Nayak,24,9848022334,trivendram
008,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai
```

#### params.init (file to hold all parameters)

```
fileName='hdfs://horton/user/jgosalia/students.txt'
cityName='Chennai'
```

#### filter.pig

```
students = LOAD '$fileName' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, age:int, phone:chararray, city:chararray);
students = FILTER students BY city == '$cityName';
DUMP students;
```

#### OPT 1: Using params on command line (-param or -p) & Output

```
pig -param fileName='hdfs://horton/user/jgosalia/students.txt' -param cityName='Chennai' filter.pig

... Trimming the logs ...

(6,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai)
(8,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai)
```

#### OPT 2: Using params file on command line (-param_file or -m) & Output

```
pig -param_file params.init filter.pig

... Trimming the logs ...

(6,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai)
(8,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai)
```

NOTE: use absolute path for file paths (both as parameters and when giving param file path to -param_file (-m)).

Comment: note to python users: if using subprocess.call(pig_cmd.split()), surround pig_cmd with double quotes, e.g. pig_cmd = "pig -param input_file -param output_file pigscript.pig"

Answer (score 2):

It is simple to pass in parameters to a PIG script.

First mark your variables in pig using '$' for example $input_file.  Then pass the parameters to you script using pig -params input_file='/path/to/data'

for more information look here: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You can pass parameters along commandline options using pig's `param` option.

```
--customparam.pig
--load hdfs/local fs data 
 original = load '$input' using PigStorage('$delimiter');
--filter a specific field value into another bag  
 filtered = foreach original generate $split; 
--storing data into hdfs/local fs 
  store filtered into '$output';
```

> pig -x local -f customparam.pig -param input=Pig.csv -param
>   output=OUT/pig -param delimiter="," -param split='$1'

For more info: [check this](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/custom-parameters-to-pig-script.html)

Comment: Please add the gist of your post on the other site here. If the other site's link dies, then link rot will occur.