# Apache Pig: How to concat strings in load function?

Tags: bash, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and I want to use Pig to load data from a path. The path is dynamic and is stored in a txt file. Say we have a txt file called `pigInputPath.txt`
In the pig script, I plan to do the following:

First load the path using:

```
InputPath = Load 'pigInputPath.txt' USING PigStorage();
```

Second load data from the path using:

```
Data = Load 'someprefix' + InputPath + 'somepostfix' USING PigStorage();
```

But this would not work. I also tried CONCAT but it also gives me an error. Can someone help me with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, find a way to pass your input path as a parameter. (References: [Hadoop Pig: Passing Command Line Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166154/hadoop-pig-passing-command-line-arguments), https://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution)

Lets say you invoke your script as `pig -f script.pig -param inputPath=blah`

You could then `LOAD` from that path with required prefix and postfix as follows:

```
Data = LOAD 'someprefix$inputPath/somepostfix' USING PigStorage();
```

The catch for the `somepostfix` string is that is needs to be separated from the parameter using a `/` or other such special characters to tell pig that the string is not a part of the parameter name.

One option to avoid using special characters is by doing the following:

```
%default prefix 'someprefix'
%default postfix 'somepostfix'
Data = LOAD '$prefix$inputPath$postfix' USING PigStorage();
```