# Load multiple files in pig - extended

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Please help me out...
I have spent a lot of hours on this.

I have files in a folder in which i wish them to be loaded according to the order of their file name.

I have even went to the extend of writing Java code to convert the file names to match the format in the guides in the following links.

1. [Load multiple files in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630584/load-multiple-files-in-pig)
2. [Pig Latin: Load multiple files from a date range (part of the directory structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structur)
3. http://netezzaadmin.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/passing-parameters-to-pig-scripts/

I am using pig 11.0

In my script.pig,

```
    set io.sort.mb 10;
    REGISTER 'path_to/lib/pig/piggybank.jar';

    data_ = LOAD '$input' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Data') AS (data_:chararray);
    DUMP data_;
```

In shell

```
    [root@servername currentfolder]# pig -x local script.pig -param input=/20131217/{1..10}.xml
```

Error returned:

```
    [main] ERROR.org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected error. Undefined parameter : input
```

Comment: try to specify "-param input=..." before "script.pig" in command line. Also try to quote input="..." if the first thing doesn't work

Comment: your solution worked! except for the {1..10} part. Its ok when I type {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} but not {1..10}, any idea? It gives ERROR 2244 now

Comment: ok according to the 2nd link i have included, it said that expansion of {1..10} is done by Linux but not hdfs api. Any suggestion or advices?

Comment: Did you try to quote as I suggested? I thought it would disable Linux expansion. Also there might be limitations to the globs of Hadoop. Check the exact glob is supported here: http://books.google.com/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=hadoop+file+globs&source=bl&ots=i7BTSyPfXs&sig=BjABL619LfWkU_FT7d9xDyN8yDY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_dmwUpLGNIfk4QT36IHIBQ&ved=0CG0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=hadoop%20file%20globs&f=false

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why are you using input parameters.

For example for loading every file in folder MyFolder/CurrentDate/ (in YYYYMMDD format), I am using following script:

```
%default DATE `date  +%Y%m%d`;
x_basic_table = LOAD '/MyFolder/$DATE';
```

Nice day

Comment: Thanks!! I am having multiple records with the same date and time and each record is stored in individual file. The only way to know the ordering is through the file name. So i need it to load the files according to the filename(digits) (the first entry must be from the file with the smallest digit).