# Pig - Load multiple files with different schema

Tags: apache-pig

I'm working with pig to load range of files/folder hadoop which are comma separated.([this question on how to load multiple files in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630584/load-multiple-files-in-pig)

the problem is that each folder have different schema file (which is located out side of the folder) - is it possible to give also multi schema files?

Answer (score 1):

If your schema file is located outside the folder, then you have to declare the schema when you perform the load.

For example:

```
dataset_A = LOAD '/data/A' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int, project:chararray, org:chararray); 
dataset_B = LOAD '/data/B' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, beta:chararray, delta:chararray, echo:int);
```

If you had a declared schema in a .pig_schema file within the directory, you would only have to perform the load, without having to declare the schema.

```
dataset_A = LOAD '/data/A' using PigStorage('\t'); 
dataset_B = LOAD '/data/B' using PigStorage(',');
```

**/data/A/.pig_schema:**

```
{"fields":
    [{"name":"id","type":10,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},
    {"name":"project","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},
    {"name":"org","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null}],
    "version":0,"sortKeys":[],"sortKeyOrders":[]}
```

**/data/B/.pig_schema:**

```
{"fields":
[{"name":"id","type":10,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},
{"name":"beta","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},
{"name":"delta","type":55,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},
{"name":"echo","type":10,"description":"autogenerated from Pig Field Schema","schema":null},],
"version":0,"sortKeys":[],"sortKeyOrders":[]}
```