# apache pig how to load files in a filenames.txt

Tags: apache-pig

I have a list of file names stored in a filenames.txt. Is it possible to load them all together using a single LOAD command?

They are not in the same directory, nor with similar format, so it is not like using /201308 to load 20130801.gz through 20130831.gz.

Plus there are too many files in the list, preventing me to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789777/2808828):

> shell: pig -f script.pig -param input=/user/training/test/{20100810..20100812}
>
> pig: temp = LOAD '$input' USING SomeLoader() AS (...);

Thanks in advance for insights!

Comment: How many files are in filenames.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of files are reasonably small (e.g: in the command line you fit into ARG_MAX) you may try to concat the lines in the file into one string:

```
pig -param input=`cat filenames.txt | tr "\n" ","` -f script.pig

script.pig:
A = LOAD '$input' ....
```

Probably it would be better to list the directories rather than the individual files if it is an option for you.

Comment: Is there a system or PIG limit on the length of the value of the $input parameter?

Comment: It works. I submitted a txt containing 184 file names, total size of 13KB, and it went through.

Comment: @alexeipab You might have a memory limit of linux command line arguments. (getconf ARG_MAX)