# Remove pig directories matching pattern

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structur) about loading Pig directories from a matched pattern, but I want to run a job that deletes in the same way. I have time-stamped directories i.e. /mydir/02-03-01, /mydir/02-03-02, /mydir/02-03-03 etc and want to delete say, 02-03-01 through 02-03-01. I tried

```
rmf /mydir/02-03-{01,02}/
```

With and without quotes to no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to consider using oozie to run your pig job. Oozie allows definition of datasets and also deletion of specific instances of these datasets before starting a job.

Answer (score 0):

below one is working for me. it should be the first command in pig script.

```
   fs -rmr  -skipTrash  /user/root/mydir/02-03-{01,02};
```

`-rmr` is deprecated. you can also use this

```
    fs -rm -r   -skipTrash  /user/root/mydir/02-03-{01,02,03};
```