# Loading selected files from a directory in Pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to know  how to load  some files from a directory in Pig Script .

Let's say there are 4 files in a directory for JAN month  and those 4 file names are as below

```
 2016-01-01.txt
 2016-01-02.txt
 2016-01-03.txt
 2016-01-04.txt
```

Now my requirement is to read files from 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-03, that means taking first 3 files of JAN 2016 ..

My Pig script :

**This below line works:**

```
rec = LOAD '/home/dir/{2016-01-01*,2016-01-02*,2016-01-03*}' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**This below line does not work :**

```
rec = LOAD '/home/dir/{2016-01-{01*-03*}}' USING PigStorage(',');
```

I am getting the below error. I am using Pig 0.14 in MAPR Cluster

```
N/A     file_records    MAP_ONLY        Message:     org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input Pattern maprfs:///home/dir/{2016-01-{01*-03*}} matches 0 files. Paths with components .*, _* were skipped. 
0 additional path filters were applied
```

Could some body explain me what happened and how do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate [Load mutilple files over a date range in PIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structur)

```
rec = LOAD '/home/dir/{2016-01-0{1,2,3}*}' USING PigStorage(',');
```

or

```
rec = LOAD '/home/dir/{2016-01-{01,02,03}*}' USING PigStorage(',');
```

or

```
rec = LOAD '/home/dir/{2016-01-0[1-3]*}' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: Your Suggestion Works. Thanks Much!