# Regex to exclude files in pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I am loading the files in the folder into HDFS using Pig for processing. The folder names are in the format MM-dd-yyyy. For instance

```
/Test/02-10-2016/file1
/Test/02-11-2016/file2
/Test/20-12-2016/file3
```

Likewise /Test folder includes date from 01-01-2015 to 20-12-2016. while loading this folder I want to exclude some date files such as 02-10-2016,02-09-2016.

I know we can use regex in the load statement like

```
ex = load '/TEST/*';
```

Like this how to use regex to exclude some files in load statement?

Comment: A few examples of valid and invalid dates will be beneficial.

Comment: That's considered a glob, not a regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pig Latin: Load multiple files from a date range (part of the directory structure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structur)